Software Updater won't launch. Error in sources.list after WINE installation
I'm using Jammy Jellyfish.
Installed WINE Stable using instructions from https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-wine-on-ubuntu.
Prior to fully running .exe, WINE threw a library not found error and said to update .RDF file (nothing was done in Terminal to correct this). WINE ran .exe successfully but texts/numbers were displayed as symbols.
Currenty WINE is no longer working, unsure why, i.e. right click "Open With Other Applications" only Archive Manager appears on list of applications.
Running $ sudo apt update I receive the following error;
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_oeg_wine-builds_ubuntu_focal-jammy.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
Similarly Software Updater shows the same error.
I've included the error notifications as links below.
image - Desktop error notification
image - Software Updater error notification

This question is similar to: E: Malformed entry 54 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Clarifying question re suggested solution and my issue. Entry 1 (first line) in my sources.list in original query is a blank line. Am I correct in understanding that the suggested solution the error is in line 54. What am I to edit / should I add to the first line if there's nothing there currently? Is there a default sources.list file I can download and update my system with? Thank you in advance.

You can find a standard sources.list for Ubuntu 22.04 in this answer.
